# Web Request/Upload Failing at Very End

Tags: c#, file-upload, httpwebrequest

I find that my HTTPWebRequest Upload is failing at the very end of the upload ... as shown in **[this video @Screenr](http://screenr.com/lPc)**

My Code is like below

```
using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
{
    BinaryWriter reqWriter = new BinaryWriter(reqStream);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[25600]; // 20KB Buffer
    int read = 0, bytesRead = 0;
    while ((read = memStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0) {
        reqWriter.Write(buffer); // at the very last loop, this line causes the error
        bytesRead += read;
        Debug.WriteLine("Percent Done: " + ((double)bytesRead / memStream.Length * 100) + "% " + DateTime.Now);
    }
```

I don't know if you need more code, I just don't want to spam code here. the exception below

```
System.Net.WebException was caught
  Message=The request was aborted: The request was canceled.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.System.Net.ICloseEx.CloseEx(CloseExState closeState)
       at System.Net.ConnectStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)
       at System.IO.Stream.Close()
       at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()
       at QuickImageUpload.ViewModels.ShellViewModel.UploadImage(String filename, String contentType, Byte[] image) in D:\Projects\QuickImageUpload\QuickImageUpload\ViewModels\ShellViewModel.cs:line 190
  InnerException: System.IO.IOException
       Message=Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.
       Source=System
       StackTrace:
            at System.Net.ConnectStream.CloseInternal(Boolean internalCall, Boolean aborting)
       InnerException:
```

Notice the inner exception "Cannot close stream until all bytes are written.". But I havent close any streams in this loop have I?

Comment: @Darin Dimitrov, I am not good at explaining things, so I thought a Video will be worth 2k words ... something noone will bother reading ... lol

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, you're closing the stream by putting it in a `using` statement - but you *should* be closing it, so that's unlikely to be the issue.

A couple of points to start with:

- I wouldn't use a `BinaryWriter` here. It's not buying you anything. Write directly to the stream.
- If `memStream` is a `MemoryStream`, you can use `WriteTo`:

  ```
  using (var reqStream = req.GetRequestStream())
  {
      memStream.WriteTo(reqStream);
  }
  ```

  That means you won't get your diagnostics, but it does make the code simpler :)

Now, as for what's going on... my *guess* is that you're getting an exception in the call to `Write`, but that exception is being effectively replaced by an exception being thrown by closing the stream.

I have an idea why an exception may be thrown, too...

Are you setting the content length anywhere? Because you're probably going over it. Look at this line:

```
reqWriter.Write(buffer);
```

This is writing the whole buffer out on *every* iteration of the loop, ignoring how much data you've just read. You've already assigned the number of bytes read into the variable `read`, but then you're never using that value. You can fix this by changing it to

```
reqWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

... but I personally wouldn't. I'd *either* just use `MemoryStream.WriteTo` *or* write directly to the request stream... as I said before, the `BinaryWriter` isn't actually buying you anything.

Anyway, in your current code for every request you'd try to write a multiple of 25600 bytes, regardless of your content length. I wouldn't be surprised if the request stream noticed that and threw an exception. Let's pretend we have 30000 bytes of data. I suspect the sequence goes something like this:

- Content length is set to 30000
- Obtain stream and enter using statement
- Read 25600 bytes from memory stream
- Write 25600 bytes out: stream validates that that's correct
- Read 4400 bytes from memory stream (i.e. all the remaining data)
- Try to write 25600 bytes: stream *immediately* decides that's invalid, and throws an `IOException`
- The implicit `finally` block of the `using` statement then disposes the stream, which closes it
- The stream notices that only 25600 bytes have been successfully written, which isn't enough, so throws an exception

It's this sort of thing that makes it a bad idea for libraries to throw exceptions from `Dispose`... but assuming I'm right, it does give the amusing problem that you've simultaneously tried to write too much *and* too little data :)

Comment: You got it right `reqWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read)` solved the problem. Like you said, in the last pass when there is less than 25600bytes, it tried to write 25600 bytes + content length is set, so the exception occurs. Also I wanted to track progress, `memStream.WriteTo(reqStream)` will give me no way to track progress?

Comment: @jiewmeng: Well, it partly depends on whether the request stream is being buffered. If it is, then you won't really be tracking progress anyway. Otherwise, you could keep your existing code but without the `reqWriter` - just write directly to the stream instead.

Answer (score 4):

You can't write "buffer" since towards the end "buffer" does not contain 20k worth of data.

So when you do a memStream.Read it returns the number of bytes actually read. You need to use that knowledge/info when you write.

```
reqWriter.Write(buffer, 0, read);
```

Comment: Well, `buffer` will *always* contain 25600 bytes of data. It's not like the array itself grows and shrinks. They may just not be very *useful* bytes.

Comment: correct, but a portion of the buffer is what he needs to write and how much is determined by how many bytes were read.

Comment: @Shiv: Absolutely - it was merely a nitpick between "does not contain 20k of data" and "doesn't contain 20k of data *that should be written*".

Comment: @Jon by "data" that's what I meant, "data" not bytes. I see that you've edited your answer to include what I said and got points for it too );

Comment: @Shiv: My answer had included the basic point before your answer was posted - but I've made it more explicit. I hope you'll admit that my answer contains rather more information than yours - including why it's actually failing.

Comment: @Jon, I beg to differ because I saw your answer as soon as I posted mine and basically it did not contain "the answer". Just to be clear, I have a tremendous amount of respect for you and what you do for the community. However, if you look at your original answer, it in no way had "the answer" to the problem. I'm ok with you getting the points for this too.

Comment: @Shiv: The oldest version of my answer in the edit logs contains: "This is writing the whole buffer out on every iteration of the loop, ignoring how much data you've just read. So every request would end up being a multiple of 25600 bytes, regardless of your content length."  (and so on). A fuller description of what's actually going wrong. It didn't contain the specific "use the `read` variable" part, but using `MemoryStream.WriteTo` would fix it anyway.

Comment: @Jon, for someone who knows, that statement would make sense. If you look at the OP's comment to your answer... Anyway, it's the nature of "game" and I don't mean to sound like you did anything wrong. So..

Comment: @Shiv: Okay. But just to point out, it wasn't like that statement was *all* that was there. It was a full description of what was going on, why an exception was being thrown, and why the exception was then being effectively "overwritten" with another exception... along with alternative approaches, and the matter of the `BinaryWriter` being unnecessary.